# Is it possible to use generic classes without type parameters?

Tags: c#, templates, generics

If I have a templated(generic) class `MyClass<T>`, is it possible to do something like:

```
var b = someObject is MyClass; // without specifying <T>
```

Comment: Have you considered inheritance? Would it make sense for `MyClass<T>` to inherit non-generic `MyClass`? In that case you can use `is` operator.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not, but you can use reflection to check the type:

```
someObject.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyClass<>))
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyClass<T>` and `MyClass` are 2 unrelated types.  You can create a relationship yourself and get the behavior you specified.

```
class MyClass {}

class MyClass<T> : MyClass {}
```

If you specify that relationship between `MyClass` and `MyClass<T>`, then your `is` operator will work in your code above.

Comment: thanks for your attempt, it was difficult to edit.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is surely misunderstood here is that, `MyClass<T>` is a 'MyClass' type that does something with type 'T'.

This is not the case.

`MyClass<T>` doesn't exist (at least conceptually) until you create an instance. Whenever such a instance is created with a type parameter, say `MyClass<int>`, It becomes a concrete type. That is `MyClass<int>` or `MyClass<float>` or `MyClass<XType>` are all different classes with similar name.These types are known as constructed Types With generics you are able to use `MyClass<>` name repeatedly otherwise you would have classes with different names. Infact Generic and Non generic implementation can exist together and treated as different types.

Example,

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
}

public class MyClass
{

}

 private static void Main()
 {
    if(typeof(MyClass)==typeof(MyClass<>)) {  }
    else {  }
 }
```

If you debug the above class you will end up in else part.

So MyClass is not a type at all until you have declared it.

Comment: You're adding to the confusion here. The reason you end up in the else part is because you're using `==` instead of `is`. Different operator which checks a different thing. It makes perfect sense that your example ends up in the 'else' clause, because you're comparing two things which are not the exact same. But if you would check "is `MyClass<T>` of type `MyClass`", that would return true (see the reflection sample posted by Selman above). You do not need an instance to do that, you can do it based on purely the types themselves using reflection.